# What mistakes were made in evaluating $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{2it}\ln(a^2-2a \cos(t) + 1)dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I'm trying to evaluate

$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{2it}\ln(a^2-2a \cos(t) + 1)dt$$

for $a \in (0, 1)$.

I keep getting different answers depending on the method.  First, if I split up the integrals in to real and imaginary parts I get:

$$ = \int_0^{2\pi} (\cos(2t) + i \sin(2t)) \ln(a^2-2a \cos(t) + 1)dt\\
= \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(2t) \ln(a^2-2a \cos(t) + 1)dt
+ i \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(2t) \ln(a^2-2a \cos(t) + 1)dt\\
= - \frac{1}{4 a^2} \left[\begin{array}&
 (a^4 + 1) t \\
- 2 (a^4 - 1) \arctan \frac{(a + 1) \tan(t/2)}{a - 1} \\
+ 2 (a^3 + a) \sin(t) \\
+ a^2 \sin(2 t) (1 - 2 \sin(2 t) \ln(a^2 - 2 a \cos(t) + 1))
\end{array} \right]_0^{2\pi} + i * 0 \\
= - \pi \frac{a^4 + 1}{2 a^2}$$

Where I got $\int \cos(2t) \ln(a^2-2a \cos(t) + 1) dt$ [from Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20cos%282t%29%20ln%28a%5E2-2a%20cos%28t%29%20%2B%201%29%20dt).  This [other online integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) gives a different but equivalent antiderivative.

Second, if I do a contour integral:

$$ = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{2it} \ln((1-ae^{it}) (1 - a e^{-it})) dt \\
= \int_0^{2\pi} e^{2it} (\ln(1-ae^{it}) + \ln(1 - a e^{-it})) dt \\
= \int_0^{2\pi} e^{2it} \ln(1-ae^{it}) + \int_0^{2\pi} e^{2it} \ln(1 - a e^{-it}) dt \\
= \oint \frac{z \ln(1-az)}{i}dz - \oint \frac{\ln(1 - a z)}{iz^3} dz \\
= 2 \pi i (0 - \frac{a^2}{2i}) \\
= -\pi a^2
$$

Third, if I ask an [online integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/), I just get 0.

I have no idea which, if any, answer is correct, or what mistakes I made in any of the methods.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your second approach is correct. The same result should be obtained by integration with $\cos(2t)$. I wonder how did you get a different result. You did not write how it was obtained.

Comment: @user I've added the additional steps in the integral.  I didn't think they were suspect since I got an equivalent antiderivative from two independent sources.  Though maybe I'm missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT.

Your second approach is correct. In the first one the expression used for the antiderivative is discontinuous at the point $t=\pi$ if the standard definition of the real $\arctan x$ function is used. To avoid this issue use the symmetry and calculate the integral as:
$$
2\int_0^{\pi}\cos(2t)\ln(a^2-2a \cos(t) + 1)dt.
$$

> You will obtain an additional summand $-\frac{\pi(a^4-1)}{2a^2}$.

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't even thought to check the antiderivative for a discontinuity except at the endpoints.